# html email: using a media query twice in a layout, works for the first instance, but not the second

Tags: html, email, gmail, media-queries

I am working on a responsive HTML email, inspired by campaign monitor's use of classes. You'll notice that each table/td width is set, but then when it hits the mobile view the media query has the table shrink.

In this examples I have two tables of different widths, with unique classes for all but one, they share one class, w80, which is supposed to handle margins. When I test this in my browser it works fine, however when I send myself a test email via putsmail my gmail app only changes the w80 for the first table, not the second.

I've stripped everything out of this email and am still at a complete loss. Any help would be amazing.

```
<html><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=320, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
<style type="text/css">

/* Mobile-specific Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { 

table[class=w640], td[class=w640], img[class=w640] { width:300px !important; }
table[class=w480], td[class=w480], img[class=w480] { width:270px !important; }

table[class=w400], td[class=w400], img[class=w400] { width:200px !important; }
table[class=w240], td[class=w240], img[class=w240] { width:170px !important; }

table[class=w80], td[class=w80], img[class=w80] { width:15px !important; }
 } 
</style>
</head>
<body>


<!--Background-->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="background-table">
<tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#f5f5f5">


<!-- Container -->
<table class="w640" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#02998e"><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="w80" width="80" bgcolor="red"></td>
        <td class="w480" width="480" bgcolor="blue">
            <p style="font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff;">why does this work</p>        
        </td>
        <td class="w80" width="80" bgcolor="red"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table> <!-- / Container Table -->



<!-- Container -->
<table class="w400" width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#02998e"><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="w80" width="80" bgcolor="red"></td>
        <td class="w240" width="240" bgcolor="blue">
            <p style="font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff;">and this does not work</p>        
        </td>
        <td class="w80" width="80" bgcolor="red"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table> <!-- / Container Table -->

</td></tr></tbody></table> <!-- / Background Table-->



</body></html>
```

Comment: Off topic: Including width values in your class names is a bad idea. What happens when you want to change the value? Will you change all the class names, too? Or will you just live with them not matching? Class names should be semantic (describing usage, not characteristics), maintaining separation of styles and markup.

Comment: Also, why `table[class=w480]` and not just `table.w480`?

Comment: You should run your code through the validator. You're using a bunch of obsolete attributes. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @isherwood - Writing code for HTML emails is a bit different than writing for a actual website:

table[class=classname] is how you write mobile stylesheets, for iphone and android. Since my problem is in gmail I removed all css that wasn't pertinent.  

html emails are not semantic, you're coding layouts in tables! Also, the code has a short lifespan. Once sent you'll never touch it again. 

HTML emails will rarely validate. Email clients don't respect all css attributes equally. For uniformity you sometimes need to use old obsolete markup to ensure the width is the same in outlook as gmail.

Comment: @isherwood This is actually due to a quirk with [Yahoo's mail client](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3457/media-query-issues-in-yahoo-mail-mobile-email/).

Comment: @astrobat Gmail doesn't support media queries, is it possible that none of it is working?

Comment: @John, the gmail app supports media queries on width (and maybe height? I dont remember) you can see it working once in this screenshot. http://imgur.com/vZjwolz